# Dojo: How do I list all items in an dojox.data.XmlStore to the console?

Tags: dojo, xml-parsing

I'm thinking this is a question with a simple answer ... I just want to loop through the items in an XmlStore and print each one out...

XML: (houses.xml)

```
<test>
  <home>
    <name>Perris, CA</name>
    <addr>123 Wilson Ave</home>
  </home>
  <home>
    <name>Palmdale, CA</name>
    <addr>345 Terrace Ave</addr>
  </home>
</test>
```

in jQuery the code looks like this:

```
$.get("houses.xml", function(xml){
    $(xml).find('marker').each(function(){
        var name = $(this).find('name').text();
        var addr = $(this).find('addr').text();
        $("<div>" + name + " - " + addr + "</div><br>").appendTo("#listDiv");
    });
});
```

I want to keep dojo relevant so it's got to be at least this simple...

so far:

```
dojo.require("dojox.data.XmlStore");
var store = new dojox.data.XmlStore({url: "houses.xml", rootItem: "marker"});
```

I can't find ANY references to looping through the XmlStore... Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks - Nigel

Answer (score 2):

It should go via standard [dojo.data.api.Read](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojo/data/api/Read). An example from [livedocs](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojox/data/XmlStore):

```
var store = new dojox.data.XmlStore({url: "books.xml", rootItem: "book"});
var gotBooks = function(items, request){
    dojo.forEach(items, function(item) {
        console.log("Located book: " + store.getValue(item, "title"));
    })
}
var request = store.fetch({query: {isbn:"a9b57*"}, queryOptions: {ignoreCase: true}, onComplete: gotBooks});
```

`onComplete` callback will give you an array of all items in the store

`onItem` callback is returned with each item

Note that if onItem is called, onComplete will be skipped. You can use on OR the other, not both for the same fetch.